# Как помигать светодиодами рандомно на одной кнопке?

Tags: arduino

Есть 7 светодиодов и одна кнопка. Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки рандомно загорался один светодиод, при следующем нажатии , гас этот светодиод и так же рандомно загорался другой светодиод. Прошу помочь направить мысль в нужном направлении.

Comment: Заводите глобальную переменную, в которую будете записывать номер светодиода. Первоначально пусть там будет -1, что будет означать, что ни один светодиод не светится. Сами светодиоды записываете в массив или вектор, чтобы удобнее было по индексу нужный выбирать. Ну а дальше генерируете номер, проверяете какой был зажжен раньше, гасите его, новый зажигаете, записываете его номер в переменную.

Comment: Только если будете брать рандом со встроенной функции random(), то инициализируйте ее случайным сидом, например значением взятым с аналогового входа, иначе значения будут предсказуемы и повторяющиеся.